# How to write Python Array into Excel Spread sheet

Tags: python, arrays, export-to-excel

I am trying to write following array into Excel spreadsheet using Python:

```
array = [ [a1,a2,a3], [a4,a5,a6], [a7,a8,a9], [a10, a11, a12, a13, a14]]
```

At spreadsheet array should look:

```
a1  a4  a7  a10
a2  a5  a8  a11
a3  a6  a9  a12
            a13
            a14
```

Is anyone can show some Python code to do it?
Thank you in advance,

Felix

Comment: What have you written so far, and how is it deficient?

Comment: How did you arrive at what the resulting spreadsheet should look like?

Comment: Thank you for all responders. Any solution w/o usage of any Python packages? Pandas solution is welcome

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/) module:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('arrays.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

array = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
         ['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
         ['a7', 'a8', 'a9'],
         ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']]

row = 0

for col, data in enumerate(array):
    worksheet.write_column(row, col, data)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Use pandas data frame!

```
import pandas as pd

array = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
         ['a4', 'a5', 'a6'],
         ['a7', 'a8', 'a9'],
         ['a10', 'a11', 'a12', 'a13', 'a14']]

df = pd.DataFrame(array).T
df.to_excel(excel_writer = "C:/Users/Jing Li/Desktop/test.xlsx")
```

excel_writer is File path in str or existing ExcelWriter object.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way that I've seen of writing to an excel spreadsheet with Python is by using [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), a library non-native to python. Another that I've heard that is occasionally used is the [XlsxWriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/introduction.html), again, though, it's non-native. Both sites have great documentation on how to best use the libraries but below is some simple code I wrote up to demonstrate [OpenPyXL](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html):

```
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

workbook = Workbook() # the master workbook
output_file_name = "outfile.xlsx" # what "workbook" will be saved as

worksheet = workbook.active() # all workbooks have one worksheet already selected as the default
worksheet.title = "foo"

worksheet['A3'] = "=SUM(A1, A2)" # set up basic formula
wb.save(output_file_name)
```

**EDIT:** For example, your request could be written as such:

```
## imports and stuff ##
array = [ [a1,a2,a3], [a4,a5,a6], [a7,a8,a9], [a10, a11, a12, a13, a14]]

workbook = Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active()

numrows = len(array)
letter = 'A'
for r in range(0, numrows):
    if r == 0: letter = 'A'
    if r == 1: letter = 'B'
    if r == 2: letter = 'C'
    ...

    numcols = len(array[r])
    for c in range(0, numcols):
        worksheet[letter.join(c)] = array[r][c]
```

Honestly this might not even work but I'm too tired to test. I think you get the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

```
print array
```

This prints the array in the Python console with square brackets marking the beginning and end of rows. Select the whole of that and copy-paste to Excel. Click on the paste icon -> Text Import Wizard. That should bring up [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I68u8.png).

Choose Fixed Width and click Next to get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJbQN.png)

Click Next and click Finish. That will do it. You'll still need to delete the ending brackets from some of the cells.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using **pandas** for your task, you can use it easily to create a dataframe and turn it into an Excel sheet. If not, it is easier to use **xlsxwriter** rather than pandas because pandas is a little heavy library.

```
pip install XlsxWriter

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("MyExcel.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
```

There are multiple ways to write the data to excel. You can use write_row(), write_column() or write cell by cell also.

*write_row(row, column, data)*

```
row = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

worksheet.write_row(1, 2, row)
```

*write_column(row, column, data)*

```
column= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

worksheet.write_column(1, 2, column)
```

*write(row, column, data)*

```
worksheet.write(0, 1, "Hello")
worksheet.write(0, 2, "World")
```

Finally, close the workbook.

```
workbook.close()
```

Like this, there are many ways to write data and also you can conditional formatting to your cells or rows or columns. The documentation can be found [here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/).